# Shared component not working when imported into lazy loading module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-module

I am trying to load one shared component inside my lazy loaded module.
module. My lazy module imports the `SharedModule` like that:

**// LazyModule**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      SharedModule,
      RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [
      LazyParentComponent
    ]
})
```

Inside my SharedModule, I am importing the Angular material components that I need for the MenuComponent which I export as a shared component:

**//SharedModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [MenuComponent],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MenuComponent
  ]
})
```

Then in my LazyParentComponent I am using `<app-menu></app-menu>` which should render the MenuComponent, which I include in the `sharedModule`.

But if I start this, I always get a lot of errors like `Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'.` or `'mat-toolbar' is not a known element.`

It does however work, if I don't use `<app-menu></app-menu>` but instead use the MatButtons from the `MatButtonModule` directly.

Comment: inside the shared module do you add the components to both declarations and exports?

Comment: I didn't include them in the descriptions but I just saw, that some of the errors go away if I include them in the imports (It's also done like that in the app.module.ts)

Comment: it doesn't sound right imports are for modules..

Comment: Oh right yes, I see. The MenuComponent is in declarations and export. I was talking about the Angular Material modules

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all material modules in imports as well:

**Shared Module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatToolbarModule
],
  declarations: [MenuComponent],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MenuComponent
  ]
})
```